# Commiting transaction in the repository instead of the application service

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, cqrs, aggregate, transaction

After quite some time thinking about it, and testing both methods, I'm really struggling with choosing the right manner to commit my transactions.

To shape the context, we are in the context of Domain Driven Design combined with CQRS.

As Eric Evan states, a transaction should only change 1 aggregate. This is kind of contradictory with most implementations I see around this stack, where a command handler saves the aggregate, and closes the transaction directly afterwards, but on the handler level and not in the repository save method.

We could easily commit the transaction in the save method, enforcing the rule of having 1 transaction / aggregate instance.

Why do most people prefer to wrap a transaction around it in the command handler, am I missing something ?

Comment: It's trivial to synthesize examples where modifications to two or more entities/aggregates are necessarily wrapped in a single database transaction. The only reason one would need to align the boundaries of *database* transactions to *domain* transactions would be to allow for maximum decoupling as it relates to scaling via sharding (i.e. "microservices"). Don't over-complicate this. Wrap each *use case* in a database transaction at the handler level and commit *any and all* changes to whichever entities/aggregates may have changed.

Comment: @king-side-slide Hmm i'd like to discuss over this. We take a use case of creating an order. We create an Order, of X Order Items containing a Product and it's amount ( very original i know :) ). We're handling 2 aggregates here, Order and Product. The order is created, an order item is created with a ProductId & amount. When this is done, the amount should be deducted from the Product stock. What I'd do is create a domain event, containing product id and amount, and let a subscriber of that event generate a command that will reduce the stock of the product. This should be done in 1 transactio

Comment: What needs to be discussed? Other than making sure you deduct the `Product` stock *before* creating the `Order`, you seem to have a handle on the system you are describing. Is there a reason the above cannot be done in 1 transaction?